# Reduce int to just 2 digits

Tags: c

I have a int that has values like 1235 and 12890. I want only the 1st 2 digits from this int. How can I extract it?

I thought for some time and couldn't come up with any solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reduce the number until you only have two digits left:

```
while (n >= 100) n /= 10;
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa. This will definitely fix the problem. Dunno why my mind has stopped working today :(

Answer (score 2):

The modulus function is your friend:

```
int n = i % 100;
```

gives the last two digits of i.

A short explanation: The last x digits of a number in any base-n representation (in your case base-10) are the part of the number that can't evenly be divided by n^x. The modulo returns the division remainder for a given number n, so modulo by n^x gives you the last-digit part.

Comment: I think that he wants the first two digits, not the last...?

Comment: @Guffa: Oh, the *most* significant digits. Thanks. Leaving the answer just in case we were running into the same old MSB/LSB trap.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implicitly uses the decimal form of the number. I think that most solutions will require you to at least convert it to decimal form or to determine a decimal-form property of it, and subsequently allow you to extract the given information.

Programmatically, you can convert it to a string, take the left two characters and convert those to an integer.

Algorithmically, determine k=floor(10log(i)), result=int(i/(10^(k-1)))